# HTML - Mailing list

Tags: javascript, html, list, email

I;m developing a website and I want people to subscribe to my blog. I want to make a list using javascript where they just input their email and it goes directly to my list like google spreadsheet. i looked everywhere and cant find anything thanks.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Node.js or PHP may be able to do what you are looking for.